# Having trouble getting Jgrasp to compile my code

Tags: java, jgrasp

Below is my code which is throwing compile-time error.

```
import Java.util.Scanner;
class gucci{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Scanner ice = new Scanner(System.in);

        int lost = 5;
        int sauce = 18;
        lost++;   
        System.out.println(lost);
        Stytem.out.println(lost);
    }
}
```

What is wrong with the code here?

Comment: it's --> import java.util.Scanner with lowercase "j"

Comment: also, you have a typo on the last System.out.println

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please find the correct one. Compare the code to have better understanding :

```
 import java.util.Scanner; // not the Java.util.Scanner
    public class Gucci{
        public static void main(String args[]){
            Scanner ice = new Scanner(System.in);
            int lost = 5;
            int sauce = 18;
            lost++;   
            System.out.println(lost);
            System.out.println(lost); // not the Stytem.out.println(lost);
        }
    }
```